# JavaScript - how do i get currentStyle of the element in Opera

Tags: javascript, styles, opera

i'm trying to get fontWeight property of the strong element in opera. and i'm stuck. this is my function:

```
getCurrentStyle: function (el, styleProp) {
    if (!el || !styleProp) return ''
    styleProp = pinecf.unifyStyleProp(styleProp)
    var y = '',
        st
    try {
        st = pinecf.getElementStyle(el)
    } catch (e) {}
    alert($(el).css(styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase()))
    if (pinecf.CAE(st, styleProp)) y = st[styleProp]
    else try {
        if (el.currentStyle) y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
        else if (pine.window.getComputedStyle) y = pine.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null)[styleProp]
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            y = $(el).css(styleProp.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase())
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    if (styleProp == 'fontWeight' && parseInt(y) > 0) {
        if (y > 400) y = 'bold'
        else y = 'normal'
    } else if (styleProp == 'fontSize' && y && y.search(/pt/i) != -1) y = parseInt(y) * 1.33
    if (!y) y = ''
    return typeof y == 'string' ? pinecf.trim(y).toLowerCase() : y
}
```

and it allways return empty value whatever method i try.

please tell me how to get real value of currentStyle in Opera browser.

any help appriciated!

Comment: Don't post minified code please.

Comment: but this code isn't minified

Comment: if it isn't, then it's just SUPER UGLY. Why don't you use spaces where appropriate?

Comment: And it IS, btw. Just look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `getComputedStyle()` part of the window object not the document?

I got it to work using this

```
for(i = 0, el = document.getElementsByTagName("strong") ; i < el.length; i++)
{ 

  cssProp = window.getComputedStyle(el[i], "cssText"); 

 //cssProp = window.getComputedStyle(el[i], null); to get all the computed css styles

  console.log(cssProp["fontWeight"])

}
```